# Apple TV conflict

Tags: appletv

Hey I seem to not be able to have airport express and Apple TV connected and the same time. I have tried various different setup methods( Ethernet, wireless . Extend, standalone) but keep experiencing drop outs with the atv . I have also tried changing settings via airport utility with no success...  Seems ridiculous that I have purchase AirPort Extreme to make these too work together . If anyone has any suggestions on how I can fix my deliemma it would be greatly appreciated?   Taylor

Answer (score 1):

I have an Airport Express and 2 ATV's, and they all get along fine, so it is possible.  First, can you take you AE out of the equation?  Does the ATV work fine (wired or wireless) without the AE?

If so, add the AE into the mix.  You haven't explained what you're using it for.  I can't think of a valid reason to have them in the same room, so I'm going to assume you either need to extend your wireless range to reach the ATV in a remote part of the house or you just want to hang some speakers on the AE's audio port.

In either case, this works for me.  Setup the AE in the Airport Utility's "Wireless" tab (in Mac OS X) to "Extend a wireless network", and make sure to send the AE's network name to the SAME as the main wireless network.  This works really well to extend you wireless network into remote parts of the house!

I guess you could be using the AE as the (only) wireless router, connected to an Ethernet-only router, and connecting the ATV to this (only) wireless network.  In that case you'd select "Create a wireless network", and join the ATB to this network.

If you could provide more info about your setup, it might help with more suggestions!

Comment: Pretty much nailed it on the head. Yes I use ae for some outdoor speakers. I am connecting the AE via Ethernet and then linking Atv off the AE . Just about to setup the unit by creating a wireless network? Is this the correct way to do it? Ta

Comment: I have previously tried to extend the network but have found the atv drops out also...

Comment: It's possible that the ATV is binding itself sometimes to the "main" wireless network, and not the AE's.  If that's far away, it might drop out sometimes, and the ATV would have to switch to the AE's (extended) wireless).  You can use Airport Utility to figure out which network it's connected to, I think.  But, running Ethernet to the AE and then a wi-fi between AE and ATV should work too.  So, yes, choose the "create wireless network" and bind ATV to it.  Only problem with this approach is that you'll have 2 wi-fi networks (diff. names) instead of 1.